# Order of ARMA models

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, arima

Why we usually do not exceed ARMA(5,5) models in practice? Is there any mathematical justification for this?

Comment: well, there are myriad examples with longer lag-length required: e.g. unployment rate in US.

Comment: @Math-fun: are you sure the unemployment rate is not more adequately captured via seasonal ARIMA, which the OP does not seem to be asking about?

Comment: @StephanKolassa it is definitely seasonal. Removing seasonality we will be left with something that has a rather sticky autocorrelation function ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of two and a half reasons.

1. The metaphysical reason: I understand why a process should depend on the previous realization, in an AR(1) model. Or even that $y_{t-2}$ may have an impact on $y_t$ *above and beyond* the influence from $y_{t-1}$ (which is already modeled by the first autoregressive parameter $\phi_1$), yielding an AR(2) model instead of AR(1). With higher and higher orders, I find it progressively harder to think of a decent justification for why there should still be an appreciable impact of the $p+1$st AR lag over and beyond what the previous $p$ lags already model.

   Of course, this does not apply to *seasonal* ARIMA, which you were not asking about.
2. The statistical reason: more parameters = more degrees of freedom = more model variance but lower bias = beyond some point, worse forecasts. The bias-variance tradeoff. Even *if* your data-generating process is AR(7), fitting a misspecified AR(5) model may yield better forecasts, in the sense of lower mean squared error. Fitting high AR orders requires *large* amounts of data.

Essentially the same points apply to moving average (MA) terms.

The half reason I can think of is that [it is hard to think of real-life moving average processes at all, apart from misspecification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45026/1352).

Comment: This is only true if the AR roots are away from unity. In financial contexts that's barely the case.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer, but you may want to think about un-accepting it and looking whether better answers come around. Questions with accepted answers get less attention. @Math-fun, for one, does not seem to agree with my arguments.

Comment: Does the argument that AR(1) can be written as MA(\infty) and vice versa, has any relation to this as well?

Comment: It may. However, I have about as much conceptual problems with AR(infty) as with MA(1) models...

Comment: And what about seasonal data? Should P and Q still be small?

Comment: @Marko: yes in that case, too. With the same argument. That (seasonal or non-seasonal) ARIMA orders will usually be $\leq 5$ is accepted wisdom among forecasters, although I couldn't find a clear source for this in [FPP2](http://otexts.org/fpp2/ch-arima.html).

Comment: @Marko: this might be helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/285099/1352