# AIC values for auto.arima

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I have a problem with identifying why auto.arima suggest specific coefficients. I have time series with multiple seasonalities and I am trying to forecast future values using STL+ARIMA. I have been following Hyndman's book (https://otexts.org/fpp2/complexseasonality.html). However, in all examples I've come across I see auto.arima function being used instead of specifying Arima parameters.

I've basically used `mstl()` function to get the remainders from Loess and then tried to estimate ARIMA parameters for these remainders. I am not sure if what I am doing is correct. I just wanted to check what `auto.arima` was suggesting.

`auto.arima` was suggesting (0,1,2) parameters:AIC= 6759.638  SSE= 4774186  p-VALUE= 0.616866 . However, majority of other models had smaller AIC values, like arima(8,0,7):AIC= 6691.219  SSE= 3820932  p-VALUE= 0.9947854. or arima(3,1,7):AIC= 6709.794  SSE= 4177168  p-VALUE= 0.9993566 .

I don't understand if what I am doing is correct and why this happens. I have checked residuals as well (Residuals from STL +  ARIMA(0,1,2)
Q* = 39.068, df = 18, p-value = 0.00279 Model df: 2.   Total lags used: 20). ( Residuals from STL +  ARIMA(3,1,7 Q* = 5.5735, df = 10, p-value = 0.8497 Model df: 10.Total lags used: 20)Any suggestions how to approach this situation ? code is below

```
data.hourly.msts=msts(ts.data,seasonal.periods = 
c(24,168),start=c(1,1))
fixed.nValid=48
fixed.nTrain=length(ts.data)-fixed.nValid
```

`datatrain.msts=window(data.hourly.msts,start=c(1,1),end=c(1,fixed.nTrain))`

```
a <-  mstl(datatrain.msts)

b<-a[,5]


for(p in 1:10){
for(q in 1:10){
for(d in 1:2){
  if(p+d+q<=20){
    model<-arima(x=b, order = c((p-1),(d-1),(q-1)),optim.control = list(maxit = 2500),method="ML")
    pval<-Box.test(model$residuals, lag=log(length(model$residuals)))
    sse<-sum(model$residuals^2)
cat(p-1,d-1,q-1, 'AIC=', model$aic, ' SSE=',sse,' p-VALUE=', pval$p.value,'\n')
   }
  }
 }
}


data.hourly.stlm=stlm(data.hourly.msts,s.window="periodic", 
modelfunction=Arima,order=c(8,0,7))
data.hourly.stlm.pred=forecast(data.hourly.stlm,h=48)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two default parameters to `auto.arima()` that are relevant here.

- First, `auto.arima()` by default limits the orders of AR and MA coefficients, as well as the amount of differencing. Here are the relevant parameters with their default values: `max.p=5, max.q=5, max.d=2`. There are very good reasons for this default behavior: [Why does default auto.arima stop at (5,2,5)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285093/1352) and [Order of ARMA models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223726/1352).
- Second, even if you were to specify higher maximum orders, `auto.arima()` might not find the AIC-minimal model, because it does by default not search all possible models, but proceeds in a greedy stepwise fashion (`stepwise=TRUE`).

You can of course *both* increase the maximum orders *and* set `stepwise=FALSE`. Be prepared for a long model selection and fitting process, especially if you have a long time series. (Or *multiple* series.)

In any case, as per [above](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285093/1352), there are good reasons not to spend too much time on higher ARIMA orders. The authors of the `forecast` package know what they are doing, and higher orders may well yield lower AICs, but they will typically not lead to smaller out-of-sample forecast errors. Have you assessed your more complicated models on holdout samples? I would strongly recommend you do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very helpful. I actually have compared auto.arima models and ARIMA with higher orders over a variety of holdout samples. Higher order ARIMA tend to perform better in every case. It's just everywhere I read it's always the same: don't use higher order ARIMA. Choose lower orders instead. Thats why its so confusing for me as I feel I am missing something important.

Comment: That is interesting. Have you tried custom methods for [tag:multiple-seasonalities], like BATS or TBATS?

Comment: Yes. I have tried TBATS. Out of 30 test I have made it shows roughly similar MAPE results as higher order STL+ARIMA models. e.g 2.3% and 2.4%. I have also tried ARIMA with Fourier terms. It tends to perform worse. e.g 4-5%