# AR Forecasting one day ahead

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive

I am doing a project where I want to forecast prices for the next day based on some lagged values of the price. When I read about how to implement this (in Python) what I find it that they use a training data set, fit the model, and then use these parameters to forecast a test data set.

For example:

```
#first until n-5 observation
df_train = df['Temp'].iloc[:-5]
#n-5 until n observation
df_test = df['Temp'].iloc[-5:]

from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
model = AutoReg(df_train, lags=22).fit()

forecasts = model.forecast(5).tolist()
test_values = df_test.tolist()
for index in range(len(forecasts)):
  difference = forecasts[index] - test_values[index]
  print(forecasts[index], test_values[index], difference)
```

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-an-autoregressive-ar-model-for-time-series-analysis-bb12b7831024)

First, I see that long training sets are generally used, but then the model uses for example 22 lags to predict the test set, like here. In this case, wouldn't it be sufficient to use this training set:

```
df_train = df['Temp'].iloc[-27:-5]
```

Which would give 22 observations?

Secondly, in my case, I don't want to use a fixed training set to forecast a set number of days in the future, but I want to use my lagged data to predict the next 24 hours.

Say if I use a 7 days lag and the first forecasting day is n. Then, to predict n, I want to use observations n-8 until n-1. For the next day, n+1, I want to use n-7 until n to predict.

So:

- Do I even need a training and test split for this forecast?
- Are you aware of some sources where I can read about this procedure?

All the best,
Simon

Comment: Sidenote (not related to answering the question): Arima can model a correlation structure based on which you make predictions, but does it also make sense for your case? Does the timeseries seem to behave like a more or less constant arima process or can there be peculiar fluctuations and variations (related to particular events in the market)? With a neural network you might pick up on more details than just extrapolating values from the previous 22 days.

Comment: Thank you @SextusEmpiricus. I realize the code I attached was confusing, I am not using 22 lags in my model, that was just an example on how AR forecasting are described in the articles I have found. The benchmark I am using use 1, 2 and 7 lags, plus min/max value from the previous day and daily dummies. I will try to beat this benchmark later with a neural network model, among others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> First, I see that long training sets are generally used, but then the model uses for example 22 lags to predict the test set, like here. In this case, wouldn't it be sufficient to use this training set: `df_train = df['Temp'].iloc[-27:-5]` which would give 22 observations?

What you are suggesting is to use 22 data points* for estimating a model with 22 slope coefficients and an intercept. That is guaranteed to yield extreme overfitting. You would not even be able to use OLS as there are more free parameters than data points. You need a much larger training subsample.

> I want to use my lagged data to predict the next 24 hours

If you have daily data, you cannot make hourly predictions. On the other hand, you probably meant forecasting 1 day ahead? That would work.

> Say if I use a 7 days lag and the first forecasting day is n. Then, to predict n, I want to use observations n-8 until n-1. For the next day, n+1, I want to use n-7 until n to predict. So: Do I even need a training and test split for this forecast?

You need a training sample to estimate the model's coefficients. Having done that, you only need the most recent $p$ data points to predict the next one. (Here, $p$ is the order of the AR model you are using.)

*I am not proficient in Python, but does `[-27:-5]` not yield 23 data points?

Comment: - My mistake, should've been [-26-5]
- It may be misleading as the example uses daily observations, but I do have hourly observations in my set. - Do you know a source where I can understand the estimation of coefficients because, in my head, a p-order AR model only uses the last p observations to predict data. And therefore older data is not necessary.

Comment: @SimonRydstedt, a model that has already been estimated does not require more than the last $p$ data points to be able to output predictions of future values. However, you need to estimate the model's coefficients first. For that, you need a larger (training) sample.

Comment: @SimonRydstedt, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

+1 to [Richard's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595138/1352). A few additions:

First off, as Richard notes, you are using the full training set to estimate the autoregression coefficients, which is what `AutoReg` does. In *forecasting*, you would only use the last 22 (or whatever your order is) observations together with the estimated coefficients.

This is completely standard autoregressive modeling, which is a subset of the more general autoregressive integrated moving average (ARIMA) class of models. You can read all about this [in this excellent online textbook](https://otexts.com/fpp3/arima.html).

Importantly, if your goal is actual forecasting, it makes a lot more sense to use an [automated ARIMA modeler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770352/452096). This will decide on the optimal AR order, but also on the number of differences and the MA order, *and* estimate the coefficients.

Any decent auto-ARIMA modeler will likely end up with *far* fewer than 22 lags. (Seasonality may come in, depending on what prices you are modeling. If this makes sense to you, be sure to allow seasonality.) See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/285093/1352) and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/223726/1352).

Comment: Thank you for the additions. I will check that book out as I think I may not understand the essence of the estimation of coefficients in the AR, as mentioned in the comment on Richard's answer. In this case, I am estimating a benchmark model so I have a set number of lags that I have to incorporate. But thank you for those sources, I will use them when I will develop my own model later.

Comment: Hm. If you are actually working on hourly data, then a seasonal model with a seasonal period of length 24 may be indicated, and make much more sense than a model with 22 lags - I have never come across a model with this lag structure before. If your benchmark uses 22 lags (but possibly no seasonality), then I would seriously question the appropriateness of that benchmark.

Comment: To clarify, this example is nothing that I am using (nor the benchmark), it is just an example of how the AR forecasting models that I have found have been described. That is, estimating coefficients once, and then forecasting. Compared to what (I think/guess) I want to do, re-estimating the coefficients every day.

Comment: @StephanKolassa the example from the link simply looked at the ACF plot and decided on 22 lags because the correlation with a lag of 23 was the first to get below a significant level. But possibly an AR(1) model might be sufficient, that also can give a significant correlation for a lag of 22. The author took as guideline, 'significant autocorrelation means that the coefficient must be non-zero'.

Comment: Great points here!

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus: thanks, good find. For the benefit of others, the argument "my last lag with an autocorrelation above the significance threshold is 22, *therefore* I will fit an AR(22) model" is false. See the bottom of [this page](https://otexts.com/fpp3/non-seasonal-arima.html) on how to select AR/MA orders based on ACF/PACF plots, which is the ancient Box-Jenkins methodology and which we keep on getting questions on here. Honestly, why anyone uses this approach rather than information criteria in 2022 is beyond me. [A question on this here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595150/1352)