# Fitting an ARFIMA Model with Covariates in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima, arfima

In R's `arima()` function, one can specify a list of covariates while estimating the AR and MA coefficients using the `xreg` argument. For instance:

```
arima(lh, c(2,0,1), xreg= 1:length(lh))
```

returns a model with ARMA(2,0) disturbance *and* the linear effect of time series `1:length(lh)`:

```
Call:
arima(x = lh, order = c(2, 0, 1), xreg = 1:length(lh))

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1  intercept  1:length(lh)
      1.3957  -0.6453  -1.0000     2.1072        0.0105
s.e.  0.1065   0.1082   0.0589     0.0585        0.0023

sigma^2 estimated as 0.1411:  log likelihood = -22.85,  aic = 57.7
```

Is there any equivalent method in R when fitting an **ARFIMA** (Autoregressive fractionally integrated moving average) model? I know it is possible to run a multiple regression on the *residuals* of an ARFIMA model, but this is different from estimating them together and would like to learn if anyone has a better suggestion.

Comment: There's a good chance that the answer is _no_, but have you tried out package [fArma](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fArma/fArma.pdf)?

Comment: Try the "rugarch" package in R, I think it has the functionality for fitting ARFIMA models with exogenous regressors. However, I am not sure whether it is ARFIMAX **or** regression with ARFIMA errors (this should become clear from the documentation and the vignette). In the latter case, it should be more efficient than fitting the regression and the ARFIMA part in two stages.

Comment: Most of R's time series libraries are wrappers of arima() so I would assume that the xreg option is always regression with ARMA errors.

Comment: @Digio, from what I know about the package, I suspect this is not the case with "rugarch", but one should check to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that feeding the `xreg` parameter in `arima()` or `auto.arima()` does not fit an ARIMAX model, but a regression on `xreg` with ARIMA errors. See [Rob Hyndman's "The ARIMAX model muddle" blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

This of course suggests how one could do a similar thing with ARFIMA: regress your observations on your covariates using `lm()` or similar, then fit an ARFIMA model to the residuals, e.g., using the [`arfima` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=arfima). Alternatively, simply use the `arfima()` function in the package and use the `xreg` parameter.

However, if you really want to fit an ARFIMAX model, then I don't know of any R package that will help. (Same for ARIMAX, though I have never explicitly searched for this, since regression with ARIMA errors makes a lot more sense to me.)

Comment: +1. I was recently searching for an ARIMAX function for R but I couldn't find one. Regressing AR(p) terms with lm() should work (it's called [ARX](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/arx.html)) but this won't work with MA(q) terms.

Comment: @Digio: you may be able to [fit a Dynamic Linear Model (DLM)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dynamic+linear+models+with+r) and constrain it appropriately.

Comment: Regression with ARMA errors is useful when one wants interpretability but doesn't really improve prediction accuracy as much as ARIMAX theoretically should.

Comment: @Digio: the operative word here being *theoretically*. Given that the top-voted answer on CV to a question asking for [real life MA processes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45026/1352) is that MA helps with model misspecification, I am kind of sceptical about the practical worth of MA(q) terms.

Comment: thanks, you clarified what not to do (this: https://365datascience.com/tutorials/python-tutorials/arimax/) but to do (this: https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/time-series-miscellaneous/arimax-model-and-forecast/)