# Real life examples of AR and MA PROCESSES

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, moving-average

As someone who has just started learning ABC of timeseries can some explain me with real - life examples of what AR (autoregressive) and MA (moving-average) MODELS helps in real life.

where AR with order of p follows :

$$X_t=\mu + \alpha_1\left(X_{t-1}-\mu\right) + \alpha_2\left(X_{t-2}-\mu\right)+ \dots + \alpha_p\left(X_{t-p}-\mu\right) + e_t$$

where MA with order of q follows :

$$X_t=\mu + e_t + \beta_1e_{t-1} + \dots + \beta_qe_{t-q}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "real-life"?

Comment: just a simple intuitive example that would help me like to imagine about the both processes

Comment: What is that you don't understand?

Comment: The question about MA is clearly a duplicate; see ["Real-life examples of moving average processes"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45026). If you search the site, you will likely find a (near) duplicate for the AR part, too.

Answer (score 0):

They are models. As somebody said: "*All models are wrong, but some are useful*".

For example, you can model stock prices *as if* they were following an AR model. Which means for example that you can try to figure out how many lags are relevant, estimate the parameters and make predictions.