# Moving Average error term

Tags: time-series, interpretation, residuals, error, moving-average

In a MA(1):

$$ y_t = \mu + \epsilon_t + \theta \epsilon_{t-1} $$

What is the error term $ \epsilon $? So far I've read that it can be:

- Difference between data and forecasted value
- Difference between previous values: $ y_t - y_{t-1} $
- Variation of other time series, like variation of temperature is $\epsilon$ and lemonade demand is $y_t$

Are all of those interpretations OK? If so what is the underlying property tying them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **first one is incorrect** unless you know the true conditional expectation of the random variable being forecast, $\mathbb{E}(y_t|I_{t-1})=\mu+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1}$, and use it as a forecast. This is unlikely in practice as you do not know $\mu,\theta,\varepsilon_{t-1}$, you may only have imperfect estimates of each of them.

The **second one is incorrect**. You can easily check that by expressing $y_t$ and $y_{t-1}$ in terms of $\varepsilon$s:
\begin{aligned}
y_t-y_{t-1} &= (\mu+\varepsilon_t+\theta\varepsilon_{t-1})-(\mu+\varepsilon_{t-1}+\theta\varepsilon_{t-2}) \\
&=\varepsilon_t-(1-\theta)\varepsilon_{t-1}-\theta\varepsilon_{t-2} \\
&\not\equiv\varepsilon_t.
\end{aligned}

The **third one is possibly correct** if we replace *variation* with *value*. E.g. suppose you are producing some good, stockpiling some of it and selling the rest. Your production in time period $t$ is $x_t=m+\varepsilon_t$ with $\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t)=0$ and your stock is $y_t$. The sequence of $\varepsilon$s is i.i.d. A $1-\theta$ fraction of the period's production is sold during the next period, and the remaining $\theta$ during the one after that. Then your stockpile is \begin{aligned}
y_t&=x_t+\theta_1x_{t-1} \\
&=\mu+\varepsilon_t+\theta_1\varepsilon_{t-1},
\end{aligned}
where $\mu=(1+\theta_1)m$. Thus, $y_t$ follows and MA(1) process.

For **real-life examples of moving-average processes**, see e.g. [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/real-life-examples-of-moving-average-processes/522254#522254), [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/real-life-examples-of-moving-average-processes/523167#523167) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45026/real-life-examples-of-moving-average-processes/525516#525516) as well as other answers in that thread. (The example to illustrate the third one above is borrowed from the latter answer.)