# Is my motivation for ARMA accurate?

Tags: time-series, arima, autoregressive, moving-average

I think I finally understand the point of the 'moving average' part of ARMA/ARIMA, but I wanted to confirm here, just in case I am still off.

Idea 1: Autoregressive processes are easy to motivate - future prices could reasonably be better predicted with current prices and perhaps the prices before today could paint an even more complete picture.

Idea 2: (Finite) moving average processes may not be as natural to motivate, but they have a lot of "niceness" properties due to the autocovariance vanishing beyond the specified window.

Idea 3: Any autoregressive process can be viewed as an $MA(\infty)$ and any moving average process can be viewed as an $AR(\infty)$ process. My understanding so far is that it's also a bit easier to deduce nice properties of $MA(\infty)$ processes from properties of their coefficients than it is for $AR(\infty)$ processes, even though they cover the exact  same processes (which is why Wold's decomposition involves an $MA(\infty)$ instead of an $AR(\infty)$ term).

Key idea: The following is a reasonable model:

$x_t\sim \varepsilon_t + \sum\limits_{i>0} \alpha^i x_{t-i}$

for some $0<\alpha<1$. Using $L$ for the lag operator, this can be written:

$x_t=\varepsilon_t + \frac{1}{1-\alpha L} x_{t} - x_t$

and collecting terms:

$(1-2\alpha L)x_t=(1-\alpha L)\varepsilon_t$

which gives us

$x_t\sim 2\alpha x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t - \alpha \varepsilon_{t-1}$

which is an $ARMA(1,1)$ model.

Punchline: Sometimes $AR(\infty)$ processes can be better approximated by rational functions in the $L$ operator than pure polynomials with the same number of terms. And multiplying both sides by the denominator of the rational function gives the "MA" side of the process.

Is there a bigger picture I'm missing?

Comment: Regarding idea 2, multiple good examples of why MA is natural and intuitive can be found in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45026).

Comment: Regarding the punchline, mine would be: ARMA is a parsimonious approximation to AR(p) or MA(q) for large p and q, so the bias-variance trade-off favors ARMA.

Comment: @RichardHardy Is your punchline that bias-variance trade-off favors ARMA(p,q) is better than AR(n) or MA(m) approximations if both n,m>p+q (and errors roughly equal) or even without that assumption? I did check out that thread but didn't fully believe the top answer and the second answer felt a bit contrived.

Comment: No, if m and n are large, then ARMA(m,n) will not make for a parsimonious approximation. They need to be small, and the beauty of it is, they can be small yet deliver a good approximation.

Comment: Yeah I agree; I think we are saying the same thing. Sometimes a short rational function in the lag can have an error so low that it takes a very large polynomial to match it - that's what ARMA outperforms pure AR.